# На какие уязвимости, помимо SQL-инъекций и XSS, стоит проверить сайт?

Tags: уязвимости, php, javascript

Давно не интересовался методами взлома, так что солидно отстал от жизни. Кто с чем сталкивался?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Я обычно анализирую следующие варианты:

- XSS
- SQL injection
- HTML Injection
- HTTP Response splitting

Загляните на [OWASP Top Ten](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project)

**UPD**

Попробуйте пройтись по своему творению [этой](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/WebScarab) системой

Comment: Cross-Site request, HTTP Response splitting и html иньекции насколько мне известно, относятся к XSS, разве нет?<br>
ИМХО некорректно вообще их как-то разделять.<br>
Т.е по сути все-равно старые "добрые" sql и xss иньекции...

Comment: Не понятно, почему их разделяет OWASP, видимо, они не догадываются что это одно и то же?

Comment: И что же, ничего нового в веб-взломе не появилось? Неужели я предусмотрел все, кроме брутфорса? Не верю...)

Comment: А это и не нужно. Из-за того, что сейчас многие полагаются на "абы работало", большинство известных атак могут быть произведены.

Comment: Ну из той ссылки что вы привели большинство тупо высосано из пальца, это как в шаблонах проектирования, там ты нередко юзаешь их сам об этом не подозревая и большинство из них откровенно высасано из пальца, так и тут... я писал что это так или иначе относится к XSS, их можно рассматривать по отдельности конечно(тогда список мягко говоря неполный), но суть и них примерно одна и таже. Вообщем че я спорить с вами буду, у каждого свое мнение по этому поводу<br>
Главное учитывать это в своих проектах :)

Comment: Плюсую:) Это не высосанные из пальца данные, это статистика, которую разбили по группам. И отсортированы по уровню риска вот [здесь](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main) сведено в таблицу с кое-какими пояснениями.

Обновил ответ

Answer (score 3):

Я бы посоветовал использовать web-scanner который бы "прошелся" бы по всему сайту и обнаружил бы уязвленные места. Для этих целей есть много различного ПО, например **Acunetix Vulnerability Scanner**. Им легко пользоваться, и анализирует он всевозможные уязвимости на сайте **(dos and ddos attacks, sql injection, php injection, XSS attack, CSRF attack и т.д)**, группируя их по степени важности. Также дает ссылки на источники где можно почитать про ошибки в том или ином ПО и как эти ошибки могут использовать хакеры, написав соответствующие **эксплойты** (иногда может также дать ссылку на эксплойт), а так же как эти уязвленности исправить/избежать.

Также стоит отметить, что всегда нужно следить за правами доступа на файлы, находящимися на web-server. Поскольку можно с помощью того же web-scanner узнать о частичной структуре директорий на сервере, что позволит запустить скрипт из web.